# Aforge BackPropagation Using

Tags: c#, neural-network, aforge, backpropagation

I am using aforge framework on visual studio. I have no error but I am getting wrong output.
My code;

```
public void btn_hesapla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        double girdi;
        girdi = Convert.ToDouble(txt_girdi.Text);
        double[] dizi = new double[1];
        dizi[0] = girdi;

        if (network != null)
            lbl_sonuc.Text = (network.Compute(dizi)[0]).ToString(); //output is range of (-1,1)
        else
            lbl_sonuc.Text = "bir hata oldu(sonuç NULL)";



    }
```

My output is range of (-1,1). But it must be like a 4,5,12,6 or something like that.
It is correct that I don't know accually that be normalize function.

(I am sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make normalize your input data and denormalize output data. For instance inputdata/100 and than outputdata*100. Try please.